# ExpressJS and VueJS: How to use express-session with Vue and Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, express-session

I'm developing an app with a Login and then another view. I want to access to the express-session in any Vue component.

I'm using ExpressJS to create the API and the express-session package.

This is my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const api = require('./api');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase');
const db = mongoose.connection;

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretKey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8081));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true
}));

app.use('/api', api);

app.use(express.static('static'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    const err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    response.json(err);
})

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error'));

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('API Server Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
});
```

Then in the router I make request.session.user = user when the user logs in

```
router.post('/user/loginUser', function(request, response) {
        User.find({ 'email': request.body.email })
            .exec()
            .then((user) => {
                response.status(200);
                request.session.user = user;
                response.json(user);
            }).catch((err) => {
                response.status(200);
                response.json({ message: 'Error user not registered', error: err });
            })
    });
```

And then in another component, when created, using Vue Lifecycle Hooks, I want to read the user from the express-session object

```
router.post('/user/getUser', function(request, response) {
        console.log('request.session :>> ', request.session);
        User.findById(request.session.user._id)
            .exec()
            .then((user) => {
                response.status(200);
                request.session.user = user;
                response.json(user);
            }).catch((err) => {
                response.status(200);
                response.json({ message: 'Error user not registered', error: err });
            })
    });
```

But when I print request.session object the user object doesn't appear

```
request.session :>>  Session {   cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true   } }
```

That is the console.log result from the getUser request.

Is there a way using express-session to access the session between Vue components? I need it because when the user is logged in I have to read all the notes the user has, and I can't do it without, at least, the _id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no problem setting a session cookie like that and then accessing it on another route.  Have you successfully logged the cookie w/user in `loginUser`?  `getUser` is redundant btw, you can have the app save the user data that's returned in `loginUser`.

Comment: @Dan The problem is that, when I want to access to request.session.user from the getUser request, the user is undefined

Comment: Yes, everything I wrote was with that in mind

Comment: So, how can I pass the user from one Store to another store?

Comment: Exactly as you did.  Set the cookie, then access it later.  You should read my first comment again and answer the question

Comment: @Dan The problem is that I make  `request.session.user = user` in the loginUser, but when I'm in another component and I do `console.log(request.session.user)` the output is undefined instead of the user saved in the login

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you make any progress?

Comment: @Tichel Finally I opted to use the vue-router params and pass the info through this